# Как работает метод notifyDataSetChanged() в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, retrofit, rxjava

Обновляю с помощью ретрофит список товаров, уведомляю о событии. В классе MainActivity вызываю метод notifyDataSetChanged(), что обычно приводит к обновлению списка в RecyclerView. Но никаких изменений я не вижу в активити. Если создать заново адаптер и прикрепить его к recycler с обновившимся списком - все отлично отображается. Не могу понять в чем причина, по логам список обновляется до вызова уведомления адаптера. Ниже прилагаю код.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RepositoryObserver {

    RecyclerView rc;
    private static BookApi bookApi;
    List<Book> books;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rc = findViewById(R.id.rec);

        Controller controller = Controller.getInstance();
        controller.addObserver(this);


        books = new ArrayList<>();

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rc.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(books);
        rc.setAdapter(adapter);


        Log.d("My_Tag", "адаптер " + rc);

        controller.getList();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBook(List list) {
        books = list;
        Log.d("My_Tag", "Уведомить адаптер " + list.size() + " " + books.size());


        Log.d("My_Tag", "адаптер " + rc);
        rc.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}




public class Controller implements Observable {
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    BookApi bookApi;

    private static Controller INSTANCE = null;
    private Set<RepositoryObserver> mObservers;

    private Controller() {
        bookApi = NetworkConnect.getApi();

        mObservers = new HashSet<>();

    }

    public static Controller getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new Controller();
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void getList() {

        bookApi.getBooks().enqueue(new Callback<List<Book>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Book>> call, Response<List<Book>> response) {
                books.addAll(response.body());
                Log.d("My_Tag", "Успешно");
                Log.d("My_Tag", String.valueOf(books.size()));

                notifyObservers();
                Log.d("My_Tag", "После вызова нотифайц" + books.size());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Book>> call, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("My_Tag", "Все по пизде");
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void addObserver(RepositoryObserver repositoryObserver) {
        if(!mObservers.contains(repositoryObserver))
            mObservers.add(repositoryObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(RepositoryObserver repositoryObserver) {
        if(mObservers.contains(repositoryObserver))
            mObservers.remove(repositoryObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers() {
        for (RepositoryObserver observer : mObservers) {
            Log.d("My_Tag", "Уведомить активити" + books.size());
            observer.onBook(books);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените

```
@Override
public void onBook(List list) {
    books = list;
    Log.d("My_Tag", "Уведомить адаптер " + list.size() + " " + books.size());


    Log.d("My_Tag", "адаптер " + rc);
    rc.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

на

```
@Override
public void onBook(List list) {
    books.clear();
    books.addAll(list);
    Log.d("My_Tag", "Уведомить адаптер " + list.size() + " " + books.size());


    Log.d("My_Tag", "адаптер " + rc);
    rc.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Причина в том, что Вы не изменяли состояние списка, отосланного ранее адаптеру, а подменяли ссылку на этот список в активности.

Comment: большое спасибо!!! заработалооооо :)